# vb.net mdi child title bar not hiding

Tags: .net, vb.net, mdi

I have an issue hiding the title bar of a mdi child form in maximized state within a mdi parent form in .NET.

Here's what I have at design & run time:
[image]

Here is the new() of my MDI child form:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef pParent As Form)
    MyBase.New()
    Me.MdiParent = pParent
    fParent = pParent
    Me.Text = ""
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.MinimizeBox = False
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.ControlBox = False
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.SizeGripStyle = Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide
    Me.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub
```

*I've tried `FormWindowState.Maximized` and `DockStyle.None` instead but the result was the same.*

On the parent container, to change from a child to another I use this function:

```
Protected Sub SetActiveScreen(ByVal pChildForm As tWizardForm)
    If pChildForm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If fActiveScreen Is pChildForm Then Exit Sub

    Dim hg As New tHourglass
    Try
       fActiveScreen = pChildForm
       fActiveScreen.Show()
       fActiveScreen.BringToFront()
       For Each aForm In MdiChildren
          If aForm IsNot fActiveScreen Then aForm.Hide()
       Next
       fActiveScreen.Execute()
       UpdateCaption()
    Finally
       hg.Dispose()
    End Try    
End Sub
```

At design I've set the parent property `IsMdiContainer = True`.

Where did I go wrong or what have I missed ?
Plus this kind of double buttons on the child title bar is really strange. When I click one of the maximize buttons I end up with the same result: 
[image]
.

The resulting title bar buttons cannot be clicked.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: Clearly you don't like MDI.  So don't use it.  That "child form" can be a user control that you dock.

Comment: @Hans Passant this might actually be the best thing to do... As I will never have several "child form" displayed at the same time and I want them always maximised. Thanks for pointing me out the obvious that I couldn't see!

Comment: I have the same problem in C# .NET ..

Comment: @StefanFalk: I followed the recommendation from Hans and transformed my MDI childs into UserControls (so they are now basically just panels) and it's way easier to deal with (especially that I only needed once displayed at a time and in maximized state).

Answer (score 4):

Here is your exact answer. It will solve your problem.

**Add a MenuStrip to MDI form and make it invisible (Visible = false)**

Answer (score 2):

I got this to working by:

1. Set the child Dock to Fill
2. Set the child WindowState to Normal (this was the magic bullet)
3. Use the Show method, not the Focus method

Answer (score 1):

Try moving

```
 Me.MaximizeBox = False
```

to the child form's Load event, this seemed to work in my project.

Comment: I've tried moving this alone and/or with other such as `Me.ControlBox = False` in the form Load but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

try the following settings for the child forms.

```
  Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```